# post and simulate CommandArgument via fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

button send request via javascript named 'dopostback' , in my code i have this function :

```
private void dlProductDetail_ItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    object left = NewLateBinding.LateGet(e.CommandSource, null, "CommandName", new object[0], null, null, null);
    if (Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(left, "DocDownload", false))
    {
        int docID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        this.ForceDocDownload(docID);
    }
    else if (Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(left, "DocPurchased", false))
    {
        int num2 = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        if (SharedFunctions.DocHasBeenPurchasedByDocID(this.UserId, num2))
        {
            this.ForceDocDownload(num2);
        }
    }
    else if (Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(left, "AddToWishList", false))
    {
        DataListItem item = e.Item;
        WishList.AddProduct(this.PortalId, e.CommandArgument.ToString(), this.UserInfo);
        this.DoAfterWishListRedirect();
    }
    else if (Operators.ConditionalCompareObjectEqual(left, "RemoveFromWishList", false))
    {
        DataListItem item3 = e.Item;
        WishList.RemoveProduct(this.PortalId, e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        this.DoAfterWishListRedirect();
    }
}
```

when i check header data in fiddler i have this data :

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="StylesheetManager_TSSM"


------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ScriptManager_TSM"

;;System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:en:9775081d-3cde-400d-a4e8-b9cd8cdf4a51:ea597d4b:b25378d2
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTTARGET"

dnn$ctr494$ProductList$dlProductDetail$ctl00$docpurchasedlink1
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTARGUMENT"


------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATE"

------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR"

CA0B0334
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED"


------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__EVENTVALIDATION"

fOIVD+nn+c54Ze/oTm31Q2zD15ye7T+OVXI9vjSGQIjAB1JhcMfiQNAYx/+RekdK1ikFDIGcBGPVUIJnv6+Rc/TrrIKWfy3Y3kOgCeI7ty52kPfTKfwv7Ks8F+fjFeez3lG0ZPeY08WtaoG9MTwaRDrRsYeNVysKfkT5bf7lVNL3mnlRYJQY1F2bvsV50EeeuoWO48Om96gix8MVtsXGI1WgWqEpaGbDZJaZV3Ovzbd5uPGg4oEgfAjTow6hiVmM1k1zQY9Pi2WsLZun
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$dnnSearch$txtSearch"


------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="dnn$ctr494$ProductList$dlProductDetail$ctl00$hfModel"

84
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ScrollTop"

800
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__dnnVariable"

`{`__scdoff`:`1`,`sf_siteRoot`:`/`,`sf_tabId`:`98`}
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="__RequestVerificationToken"

S8dMajopXeSPMN4yZOK3AD6WSx5wEwjG35vmuQ0gaYwml_tLG640bw97PiPiXd98WAfiM-A0SWreh5Bb0
------WebKitFormBoundaryLdhbAgPnI7779ZQp--
```

when i tamper `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=dnn$ctr494$ProductList$dlProductDetail$ctl00$hfModel1` value nothing change in my form data . where `int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());` get value from form post data ? as you see `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=__EVENTARGUMENT` is empty ! how asp.net know CommandArgument  ?!